# How do I check if an array is empty in Julia?

Tags: julia

I am trying to see if there's a handy way to check if an array in Julia is empty or not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Julia you can use the `isempty()` function documented [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.isempty).

```
julia> a = []
0-element Array{Any,1}

julia> isempty(a)
true

julia> length(a)
0

julia> b = [1]
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1

julia> isempty(b)
false
```

Note that I included the length check as well in case that will help your use case.

Answer (score 3):

For arrays one can also simply use `a == []`. The types are ignored in this comparison (as usual).

```
julia> a = []
a == []
0-element Array{Any,1}

julia> a == []
true

julia> a == Int[]
true

julia> String[] == Int[]
true
```

Answer (score 2):

From Julia help:
`isempty` determines whether a collection is empty (has no elements).

e.g.

```
julia> isempty([])
true

julia> isempty(())
true
```